# Set email body and subject in aura component lightning email tag

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, aura-attribute

```
 <lightning:formattedEmail value="hello@example.com?cc=email@example.com⊂ject=My%20subject &body=The%20email%20body"
                              label="Send us your feedback" />
```

Can anybody explain me the correct syntax of this tag?

Answer (score 0):

The correct format is:

```
<lightning:formattedEmail value="hello@example.com?cc=email@example.com&amp;subject=My%20subject &amp;body=The%20email%20body" label="Send us your feedback" />
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SFSE! If you haven't yet, please take a moment to read about [answer] and take our quick [tour]. Your answer could be improved by explaining what you changed to fix the code. You can [edit] your answer to improve it. We look forward to your future contributions.